# Vue.js: How to read $index inside computed function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, vue.js

I have list of links:

```
  <ul id="menu">
     <li v-for="item in items">
       <a href v-bind:href=link>{{item.message}}</a>
     </li>
  </ul>


  var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#menu',
  data: {
     items: [
        { message: 'Link1' },
        { message: 'Link2' }
     ]
  },
  computed: { 
      link: function() {
          return f($index)    // how do I access current array index ??
      }
  }
  })
```

I can achieve the desired result by using mustache markup in a `href` attribute but it must be possible to access this `$index` variable from within a computed function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't**.

This is what methods are for:

```
<a href v-bind:href="link($index)">{{item.message}}</a>

methods: { 
  link: function(index) {
    return f(index)
  }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks that looks like it will do the job perfectly! (am new to Vue)

Comment: Oops, yeah i meant methods obviously